# How to convert binary data from Outlook Mail API to image source in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, office365

I know this is a specific question, but trying other methods of conversion I've found haven't been successful so I would like answer to my specific scenario.

I'm getting a response from an API call to the Outlook Mail API. I've got to the point where I have an Attachment object ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#RESTAPIResourcesFileAttachment)). As you can see, the type of **ContentBytes** is "binary", so I've tried converting binary to a data URI that I can use as the *src* attribute of an img tag.

`var imageSource = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + btoa(attachment.ContentBytes);`

I've tried some other things as well, including converting the binary string to a Uint8array first before attempting to encode to base64.

Any ideas would be great. I've been stuck for a day and just feel like I'm wasting time now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `ContentBytes` is already base64-encoded, so have you tried leaving out the `btoa` call? What does `ContentBytes` look like if you just log it to the console?

Comment: This is correct. It even says it on the documentation page. Thank you, Jason!